# Text file to string appears weird when printed out - '(apostrophe) becomes \' (backslash apostrophe)

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.7.11 and I have a text file that contains the following string:

```
we're "rock"
```

When I use

```
with open("file name") as document:
    passage = document.read()
```

and try to print my `passage` I get

```
we\'re "rock"
```

The problem only occurs when there is " in the same text, ' will be shown as \'

Comment: Is the `'` escaped in the document, can you share the document? How are you printing out the `passage`. I can't replicate your issue.

Comment: I suggest editing the question to show the whole code, especially since the code in the question has a syntax error(dot at the end)

Comment: Hmm, tried both in Python 3 and Python 2.7, both worked fine... Show us the whole code and the text, maybe that will help.

Comment: thanks, let me try to give you a sample code and text file that has the problem

Comment: Edit your question and add the text file in it.

Comment: re AChampion, seems yes, if I use print() it prints as normal, if I write the variable directly it has the problem.